# Nested conditional using radio buttons to guide script in PHP

Tags: php, forms, radio-button, nested, conditional-statements

I've been working on this for a while and I can't seem to figure it out. I know it must be something really simple. Basically I have a script that works as a program that translates English to Piglatin, and it works fine, but I want the user to have a choice of whether or not to actually operate that script, by using a radio form with the text input that says "English" or "Piglatin". I've tried all different ways to get this to work, but using a nested conditional seems like it would be the most logical answer to me. However, whenever I try to run the script with it, it doesn't work. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?! It would be much appreciated. Thanks!

HTML Form:

```
<p><input type="text" name="original" size="20" maxlength="40" /></label></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="english" value="yes"/>english <input type="radio" name="english" value="no"/>piglatin</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php # script
$original = $_REQUEST['original'];
$english = $_REQUEST['english'];
$array = explode(" ", $original);

if($english=="no")
{
piglatin = "";
foreach($array as $word)
{
    $word = trim($word);
    $first = substr($word,0,1);
    $rest = substr($word,1,strlen($word)-1);

if (preg_match('/^[aeiou]/', $word)) {
    $word = preg_replace('/^([aeiou].+)$/', "$1-way", $word);
}

elseif (preg_match('/^(th|sh)/', $word)) {
    $word = preg_replace('/^(th|sh)(.+)$/', "$2-$1ay", $word);
}

    else {
       $word = preg_replace('/^[a-z](.+)$/', "$1-$first"."ay", $word);
    }

    $piglatin .= $word ." ";


echo $original ." becomes: ".$piglatin.".";
};

else
{echo $original.".";
};


?>
```

Like I said, I'm sure it's something really small and simple that I just can't see because I've been looking at the code so long. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: }; else should read } else

Comment: oh thats closing your foreach.  try }; } else

Comment: You need a better editor I think. Any php IDE will throw errors for missing brackets + vars with $.

Comment: Closing brackets!This is one of the advantages of aligning the code

Comment: Wow, I swear I triple checked for brackets! I knew it would be something simple, didn't realize it would be something THAT simple. Thank you so much everyone! I'll work on aligning my code a little better next time :)

Comment: ..Also the missing $ on piglatin = "";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your indentation out and you will see your missing closing brackets.

```
<?php # script
  $original = $_REQUEST['original'];
  $english = $_REQUEST['english'];
  $array = explode(" ", $original);

  if($english=="no")
  {
    $piglatin = "";
    foreach($array as $word)
    {
      $word = trim($word);
      $first = substr($word,0,1);
      $rest = substr($word,1,strlen($word)-1);

      if (preg_match('/^[aeiou]/', $word)) {
          $word = preg_replace('/^([aeiou].+)$/', "$1-way", $word);
      } elseif (preg_match('/^(th|sh)/', $word)) {
          $word = preg_replace('/^(th|sh)(.+)$/', "$2-$1ay", $word);
      } else {
          $word = preg_replace('/^[a-z](.+)$/', "$1-$first"."ay", $word);
      }
      $piglatin .= $word ." ";
      echo $original ." becomes: ".$piglatin.".";
    };
  } else {
    echo $original.".";
  };
```